# Can one thread interrupts another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I'm wondering whether it is illegal to interrupt another thread in the first thread's run method. If yes, when I invoke another thread's interrupt method in the first thread's run method, will a "InterruptedException" be thrown? Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {

        }
    }, "thread1");
    try {
        thread1.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Oops! I'm interrupted!"); 
    }
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("I will interrupt thread1!");
        thread1.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Thread1 interruption done!");
    }, "thread2");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

But I got no message "Oops! I'm interrupted!" in the Console.

Comment: You should be getting an "Accessing a static method through an instance" warning on the line thread1.sleep(). That's warning you about what Keppil is saying in their answer

Comment: I've got this. Thank you very much all the way! --)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your program doesn't work is that you are using the `thread1` reference to access the static `sleep()` method, but the sleeping is still executed in the main thread.
Move it into the body of `thread1`, and your program works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops! I'm interrupted!");
        }
    }, "thread1");

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("I will interrupt thread1!");
        thread1.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Thread1 interruption done!");
    }, "thread2");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

This prints:

```
I will interrupt thread1!
Thread1 interruption done!
Oops! I'm interrupted!
```

Note that the order of the last two printouts depends on the thread scheduling, and may vary.

Comment: Fancy! I appreciate you very much!